# How to use OKHttp with async calls and callbacks?

Tags: android, okhttp

Investigating [OKHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and want to use as docs claims possible: "It supports both synchronous blocking calls and async calls with callbacks".

But how can I set a callback, or a chunk of code needs to execute after response received? I have not find anything on their site.

Should I nest call into an `Async` thread like:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//TODO your background code
```

Comment: Why -1? I do not agree.

Comment: Don't you know `Retrofit` ?

Comment: @MD somewhat I know, what advantage it has?

Comment: @MD retrofit if for REST, okhttp is for HTTP, not to confuse them.

Comment: @Janos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: @RobertEstivill So what's problem ? `Retrofit` is integration of `OkHttp3`. It's completely customised version

Comment: @MD wrong. Retrofit is a convenient library that implements REST logic on top of OkHttp, which is the http layer library. They work on completely different layers, although they integrate very well because they are both developed by Square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sample

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
          if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

          Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
          for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
          }

          System.out.println(responseBody.string());
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Coincidence. The example runs the code like such `new AsynchronousGet().run();` take a look at the link with the full example